# Blur a form, except its submit button, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form:

```
<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

when submitting, I want to blur the whole form:

```
$(this).closest('form').css({
 'filter' : 'blur(1px)'
});
```

unfortunatly this also blurs my submit button too. How to make this exception?

Comment: So put the elements inside a new element and blur that instead of the whole form

Comment: Not sure why JavaScript is even needed, just a simple CSS Selector. Add a class to the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do this is by blurring all of the children DOM elements of the form except for the submit input. You could do this by attribute selectors with jQuery or simple class names. Below is an example using class names:

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" class="visibile-on-blur">
</form>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$('#myForm').submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).children(':not(.visibile-on-blur)').css({
    'filter' : 'blur(1px)'
  });
});
```

Refer to the fiddle below.
https://jsfiddle.net/sotjrvco/1/